# Erro ao tentar executar função de Insert PDO - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

estou tentando criar uma função PDO para executar duas inserções, uma em seguida da outra, mas estou com dificuldades.

O código da função é:

```
public function double_cad(array $dados){
    $pdo = parent::getDB();
    $double_cad = $pdo->prepare("insert into login(nome, login, senha, role)values(?,?,?,?)");
    $double_cad->bindValue(1, $dados[0]);
    $double_cad->bindValue(2, $dados[1]);
    $double_cad->bindValue(3, $dados[2]);
    $double_cad->bindValue(4, $dados[3]);
    $double_cad->execute();

    $id_usr = $pdo->lastInsertId();

    $double_cad = $pdo->prepare("insert into transacoes(codigo_transacao, referencia, status_transacao, ".$id_usr. ", id_servico, tipo_pagamento, data_transacao)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $double_cad->bindValue(1, $dados[0]);
    $double_cad->bindValue(2, $dados[1]);
    $double_cad->bindValue(3, $dados[2]);
    $double_cad->bindValue(4, $dados[3]);
    $double_cad->bindValue(5, $dados[4]);
    $double_cad->bindValue(6, $dados[5]);
    $double_cad->bindValue(7, $dados[6]);
    $double_cad->execute();

}
```

O que estou tentando fazer é inserir os dados do usuário na tabela "login", recuperar seu id e, logo em seguida, inserir na tabela "transacoes" os dados da transação desse usuário (a linha "$id_usr = $pdo->lastInsertId();" é justamente para recuperar o id do usuário para inserir como chave estrangeira na tabela de transações).

Porém, ao executar esta função, exibe o erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, id_servico, tipo_pagamento, data_transacao)values('nome do usuário','email do usuário' at line 1' in C:\wamp\www\xxxx\lib\class\Transacao.php on line 44

A linha 44 é justamente o segundo execute da função. Como resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sintaxe do insert é:

```
INSERT INTO TABELA (CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3) VALUES (VALOR_CAMPO1, VALOR_CAMPO2...)
```

Mas nessa linha você usa o id que retornou da ultima query para listar as colunas:

```
insert into transacoes(codigo_transacao, referencia, status_transacao, ".$id_usr. ", id_servico, tipo_pagamento, data_transacao)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Gerando um insert na coluna "1" por exemplo então se você não tiver uma coluna com o nome 1 ele não vai inserir.

Comment: É isso mesmo! Estava inserindo a variável no lugar errado... O correto, como vc mesmo disse, é manter o nome da coluna no INSERT: `insert into transacoes(codigo_transacao, referencia, status_transacao, id_usr, id_servico, tipo_pagamento, data_transacao)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");` E inserir a variável na linha: `$double_cad->bindValue(4, $id_usr);`